# How to update SBT version using homebrew?

Tags: scala, sbt, homebrew

I installed SBT v0.12.4. Now I want to update it to v0.13.x, so I have used the command

```
brew install sbt
```

It says that it has correctly installed SBT 0.13.x. but if I ask on terminal the version of SBT, it says 0.12.4. How to update it?

Comment: What is the output of the following commands `ls -l /usr/local/bin/sbt` and `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/sbt*`?

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 alessio.crestani  admin  28  3 Nov 15:50 /usr/local/bin/sbt -> ../Cellar/sbt/0.13.6/bin/sbt and for the second command it gives me 0 total result.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two sbt versions:

1. The `sbt-launcher`. This is used to download and run a particular sbt version.   This is what you installed with brew.  If you type `sbt --version` it should tell you the version of the launcher brew installed.
2. sbt itself (for building projects).  This is controlled via a `project/build.properties` file *by project*.  So one launcher can launch many versions of sbt, and is generally backwards compatible.  To update this version, simple change the `sbt.version` property in `project/build.properties`.

Comment: thanks, my launcher is 0.13.6 and in the project 0.12.4. I don't see the `build.properties` because android studio doesn't show mw up this file, I've to manually enter with finder on the folder.

Comment: `sbt --version` does not work for me currently, (running  0.13.12 btw), but I need to run `sbt sbt-version` to get the version information.

Comment: `sbt sbt-version` didn't work for me - `sbt sbtVersion` did though.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to upgrade the version of sbt installed by homebrew, use:

```
brew upgrade sbt
```

You can check what version of sbt is in use with `sbt about`

Answer (score 6):

check sbt version:

```
sbt sbtVersion
```

upgrade sbt version:

```
brew upgrade sbt
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative `sbt-launcher` with source code here [paulp/sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) that allows specifying sbt version within command line.

Installing sbtx

```
brew install --HEAD paulp/extras/sbtx
```

Or

```
curl -Ls https://git.io/sbt > ~/bin/sbt && chmod 0755 ~/bin/sbt
```

Building project with desired sbt version

```
sbt -sbt-version 1.2.5 clean test
```